# Unresolved external symbol for variables in namespace

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern, unresolved-external, lnk2001

I have problem with LNK2001: unresolved external symbol error. It shows only when I have all my classes in my namespace and refers to global variables which I use multiple files. Here is example code how my codes look like:

**Engine.h**

```
#pragma once
namespace Engine{
    #include "Core.h"
    #include "Display.h"
    #include "Box.h"
    // ... some code...
}
using namespace Engine;
```

**Core.cpp**

```
#include "Engine.h"
// ...some code...
```

**Core.h**

```
extern Matrix matrix;

// ... some code...
```

**Display.cpp**

```
#include "Engine.h"
Matrix matrix;

// ... some code...
```

**Display.h**

```
// ... some code...
```

**Box.cpp**

```
void Box::draw(PxShape *shape){
    // matrix=.. some code...
}
```

**Box.h**

```
// ... some code...
```

**Error message**

> 1>Box.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct Engine::Matrix Engine::matrix" (?matrix@Engine@@3UMatrix@1@A)

When I comment namespace everything works as it should. It is the first time when I want use a namespaces and I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: There is absolutely no reason to define a namespace `Engine` if in the same header file that defines this namespace, you introduce all elements of the `Engine` namespace into the global namespace.

Comment: Before defining a namespace I have also included some 3rd party libraries and standard c++ headers and I wanted to indicate that these classes are provided by me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `#include` directives (and therefore your interface definitions) are inside `namespace Engine`, but it appears your implementations are not.  That's giving you the link error.

You need to wrap the body of code in each of those .cpp files in `namespace Engine` also.

ie:

```
 #include "engine.h"
 namespace Engine
 {
     // implementation goes here
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought .cpp files are automatically included into headers namespace.

Comment: Thanks! It resolved my issue. saved a bunch of my time.